# Firebase. Login with Google account

Tags: firebase, web

When logging in through a domain
https://online-shop-34af2.web.app/
the google account selection window remains visible.

But when logging into the domain
https://damask.in.ua/
the window appears and disappears abruptly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an easy fix, you need to authorize your "https://damask.in.ua/" domain [image]

goto Project->Authentication->Sign in method->Authorized domains and then just there add your .ua website and you are done!